# Installation of RED 5 On Server (Windows Server 2012R2)

Tags: windows, server, red5

I am trying to install Red5 on server (Windows Server 2012R2) so that I can use it remotely.
What I have tried till now...

case 1:

```
-set the path for java jre.
-I installed red5 with ip 127.0.0.1 with port no 5080 (already opened this port)
-Start the red5 service.
-Working fine.
```

But the problem is It's working as localhost, I was not able to access it as remotely then I changed "red.properties" and set rtmp.host to my server IP, 
But It didn't work for me.

Case 2:

```
-I reinstalled red5 server with my server IP with port 5080
-open 5080 port on firewall
-start the server
```

This setting also didn't work for me.

Where Should I make change to access it remotely..?

Answer (score 0):

Assign correct ip in red5.properties

Change passwords in realm.properties

Open firewall for port 1935 for RTMP and 5080 if you want to access the webserver

(control panel - system and security - windows firewall - advanced settings - new inbound rule - port tcp)

Red5 guide for more installation techniques and videos : [link](http://red5guide.com/install_red5_on_windows.html)

Comment: :I have assigned correct IP and opened the port also....I have a little confusion about realm.properties, which user name and password we have give here, instead of default admin?